# Releasing objects created by functions

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I'm learning obj-c and I have a question about memory management:

Say I have a function that returns an NSDictionary, "fDictionary",

```
NSDictionary *fDictionary {
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], @"blah",nil];
return dict
}
```

that is called by a particular method:

```
-(int)fNumber {
  NSDictionary *f = fDictionary();
  return [[f objectForKey:@"blah"] intValue];
}
```

What I'm unclear about is how/where I should be releasing the NSDictionary object.

Should I release it in the method, or autorelease it in the function?

Comment: That depends on the code of the `fDictionary` function. Please post it as well.

Comment: I've edited the post to include the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the function was written properly, the dictionary is autoreleased, so you don't have to release it at all. It will be released soon, by the autorelease pool.

You only release what you yourself retain or copy. These are the things you "own". Be sure not to release them too early. The usual point is before the end of the function they are allocated or retained in, if they are local. If they are ivars, the best point is, usually, the dealloc of the class to which the ivar belongs.

Comment: So if I needed to return the dictionary for use elsewhere in the code, then I would need to retain it, but in the example above I wouldn't?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing anything about `fDictionary` it's difficult to be sure, but the convention followed in most Object C code is as follows:

- You own it if the instance was created with an `alloc` or `copy`
- You own it if you `retain` it
- Otherwise you don't own it

If you don't own it you should not `release` it.

So by convention, the function would return an `autorelease`d object and you wouldn't need any extra management in your method.

Answer (score 1):

The general rule is if your code alloc's something, you need to release or auto-release it.

If this was someone else's function, you would expect that the returned dictionary was autoreleased - which is the convention here.  I would ensure that fDictionary returns an autoreleased NSDictionary.

Answer (score 0):

If you have received an object from a method which name begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy”, you have to release or auto-release it. Otherwise it is already autoreleased.

If you have retained something, you have to release it, nothing else will do that for you.

Every Obj-C programmer must read [Memory Management Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/).

Answer (score 0):

No.

`NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:` (which is really just `[[[NSDictonary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:, nil]autorelease]`) returns an autoreleased `NSDictionary`. This means the dictionary will automatically be released when the computer decides it is no longer needed.

If in `fDictionary()` the dictionary was `alloc`ed, you would need to release it manually. It is a rule of thumb to always return autoreleased objects from functions/methods, so the user of the functions/methods does not have to worry about memory management.